# How to ignore block region placements during config sync?

Tags: configuration

When we perform config export and import our block placements are getting hosed. Is there a way to no export block placements/regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Config Ignore](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_ignore) module lets you configure configs to ignore during import and export.

Comment: We are already using config split (which doesn't really seem to work well). If config Ignore better than config split?

Comment: They are different.. Config Ignore prevents config from ever being imported. Split exports to different locations and also imports from those locations. If you are trying to use config split to "ignore" some config, e.g. your block placements, make sure the config you want exists on your destination in the split's defined location or the configuration will be deleted on import (same as if you weren't splitting and remove from sync directory).